# Highcharts js set last month x axis data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set last month `xAxis` of dynamic data dynamic data.

[image]

If the graph last value month is aug 20, it should follow in previous months too. e.g. aug 19, aug 18, aug 17. And if it is oct 20, it should be oct 19, oct 18, oct 17.

Highcharts xAxis is `datetime` it is adjusting as per dynamic data.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels:{
          /*formatter: function(){
            var getDate = new Date(this.value);
            var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            var mMonth = getDate.getMonth() === 0 ? 11 : getDate.getMonth() - 1;
            return months[mMonth] +', '+ getDate.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
          },*/
          //offsetY:-10000,
          //enable:true,
          //distance:100,
          //align:'right'
          //skew3d:true
          //x:-30,
          //y: 0
          //left:1000
          //align: 'left',
        },
        //tickPixelInterval: 72,
        //visible:false,
        endOnTick:true,
        //endOnTick:true,
        //tickmarkPlacement:'on',
        //tickWidth: 1,
        //min:1
        //offset: -30,
        //enabled:false,
        //offsetX:-100
          //
        //left: -10
    },
    yAxis:{
        offset:0
    },
  /*plotOptions: {
    line : {
      dataLabels : {
        enabled : true,
        formatter: function() {
          var first = this.series.data[0],
              last  = this.series.data[this.series.data.length - 1];
          //return this.x;
          if ((this.point.category === first.category && this.point.x === first.x) ||
              (this.point.category === last.category  && this.point.x === last.x)) {
              console.log(this.x);
                 //return this.x;
          }
          return "";
        }
      },
    }
  },*/
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [
          [1596240000000, 5.32],
          [1593561600000, 8.12],
          [1590969600000, 11.29],
          [1588291200000, 5.35],
          [1585699200000, 5.99],
          [1583020800000, 7.97],
          [1580515200000, 6.98],
          [1577836800000, 4.59],
          [1575158400000, 3.63],
          [1572566400000, 3.85],
          [1569888000000, 9.98],
          [1567296000000, 5.53],
          [1564617600000, 9.72],
          [1561939200000, 10.61],
          [1559347200000, 6.13],
          [1556668800000, 8.23],
          [1554076800000, 7.77],
          [1551398400000, 4.38],
          [1548979200000, 5.11],
          [1546300800000, 6],
          [1543622400000, 5.59],
          [1541030400000, 5.35],
          [1538352000000, 3.87],
          [1535760000000, 1.94],
          [1533081600000, 4.33],
          [1530403200000, 4.16],
          [1527811200000, 3.18],
          [1525132800000, 4.38],
          [1522540800000, 3.43],
          [1519862400000, 7.92],
          [1517443200000, 3.45],
          [1514764800000, 4.14],
          [1512086400000, 3.38],
          [1509494400000, 4.99],
          [1506816000000, 6.02],
          [1504224000000, 4.11],
          [1501545600000, 6.19],
          [1498867200000, 7.33],
          [1496275200000, 5.06],
          [1493596800000, 5.01],
          [1491004800000, 2.93],
          [1488326400000, 1.2]
        ]   
    }]
});
```

```css
/* .highcharts-axis.highcharts-xaxis .highcharts-tick{
  transform:translateX(-30px);
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi @Snehal_tupe, Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve? Do you need to adapt all `x` values to the last `x` value?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, yes last `x` axis value should adapt and follow previous month. E.g. If last month ends with Oct 20 then previous months should follow oct 19, oct 18, oct 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tickPositioner` and `labels.formatter` functions:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        tickPositioner: function() {
            var ticks = [],
                dataMax = this.dataMax,
                oneYear = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12;

            for (var i = dataMax; i >= this.dataMin; i -= oneYear) {
                ticks.push(i);
            }

            return ticks.reverse();
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %y', this.value);
            }
            ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9cunk5xw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner